# Flex: Align all children at flex-start but force one child to end?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flex container with 3 children, and I am wanting to ensure that the children all align at `flex-start`, however the final child should sit at the bottom of the container.

Is it not possible to combine `align-content` with `align-self`?

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: flex-start;
    padding: 15px 15px 50px 15px;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 500px;
}

.item-1,
.item-2,
.item-3 { width: 100%; }

.item-3 {
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-1">One</div>
  <div class="item-2">Two</div>
  <div class="item-3">Three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not use a flex **-column**...much simpler then

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you want 100% width of your element, you can switch to column direction then use margin to control alignment:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 15px 15px 50px 15px;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}

.item-3 {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-1">One</div>
  <div class="item-2">Two</div>
  <div class="item-3">Three</div>
</div>
```